# Change Touch Keyboard layout (InputScope) for AutoSuggestBox

Tags: c#, uwp

In UWP, there's a InputScope method available for TextBox and RichEditBox which can be used to define keyboard layout for different types of input. 
But the problem is that there is no InputScope for AutoSuggestBox. I'm using AutoSuggestBox for inputting URIs and hence I need '.com' button to appear on touch keyboard.

I know AutoSuggestBox is derived from TextBox class (probably) and so it should work with inputScope method. I used this hack-

```
 private void AutoSuggestBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InputScope keyType = new InputScope();
        InputScopeName typeOfKeyboard = new InputScopeName();
        typeOfKeyboard.NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.Url;
        keyType.Names.Add(typeOfKeyboard);
        (e.OriginalSource as TextBox).InputScope = keyType;  
    }
```

But it still doesn't work. Are there any alternative solutions for this problem as I do not want to replace ASB with any other input type.

Comment: It isn't derived from TextBox. You can see it for example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox).

Comment: The hack that I mentioned in question works but not perfectly. When the autosuggestbox gets the focus for the first time, keyboard layout remains normal but for all following calls to the box, keyboard appears as required (with '.com' key). So conclusion is that it is derived from textBox or if not then both have same parent class at least. @MarianDolinský

Comment: @MarianDolinský, I'm looking up for a solution which will work in any circumstances whether the app is launched just now or it has been in the memory already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet should work after the [`AutoSuggestBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox) get focused first time. Before the `AutoSuggestBox` get focused first time, the `InputScope` is the default value, so when it is first focused, new input scope does't take effect, from second focus it will take effects.

`AutoSuggestBox` is actually composed of a `TextBox` and a `Popup`. To change the input scope of `AutoSuggestBox` is actually to change the input scope of the inside `TextBox` of `AutoSuggestBox`.  So update the template of `AutoSuggestBox` as follows:

```
<AutoSuggestBox x:Name="autosuggestbox">
    <AutoSuggestBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="AutoSuggestBox">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="AutoSuggestBox">
                        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                            <TextBox
                                x:Name="TextBox"
                                Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                                Margin="0"
                                Canvas.ZIndex="0"
                                DesiredCandidateWindowAlignment="BottomEdge"
                                Header="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                InputScope="Url"
                                PlaceholderText="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
                                ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False"
                                Style="{TemplateBinding TextBoxStyle}" />
                            <Popup x:Name="SuggestionsPopup">
                                <Border x:Name="SuggestionsContainer">
                                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="UpwardTransform" />
                                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                                    <ListView
                                        x:Name="SuggestionsList"
                                        MaxHeight="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestListMaxHeight}"
                                        Margin="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestListMargin}"
                                        Padding="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestListPadding}"
                                        Background="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionsListBackground}"
                                        BorderBrush="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionsListBorderBrush}"
                                        BorderThickness="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestListBorderThemeThickness}"
                                        DisplayMemberPath="{TemplateBinding DisplayMemberPath}"
                                        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                                        ItemContainerStyle="{TemplateBinding ItemContainerStyle}"
                                        ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplate}"
                                        ItemTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}">
                                        <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                                            <TransitionCollection />
                                        </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                                    </ListView>
                                </Border>
                            </Popup>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Orientation">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Landscape" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Portrait" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </AutoSuggestBox.Style>
</AutoSuggestBox>
```

More details please reference [AutoSuggestBox styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185404.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for a great answer, but it lacks a bit of explanation. Anyways, provided solution worked for me like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

You may edit the template of the `AutoSuggestBox`and set the `InputScope` to the `TextBox` in XAML. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185404.aspx) you can find the default template of `AutoSuggestBox`.